# Mysql too Slow when Copying to Tmp Table

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join, left-join

I have data split across several mysql tables to prevent data duplication but joining them is too slow when I actually go to serve the data.  I am thus building a much smaller cache table of the data which is likely to be needed in the near future (certain data is only relevant for a small time frame so the whole tables are ~700,000 rows but the cache is ~6,000).
Building this cache uses a temp table before copying into the actual cache table so that while the table is built each night, the live cache table doesn't go down.  Sometimes the cache table gets built in about 30 minutes, but other times it gets stuck and will never complete.  In the process list it just says `Copying to tmp table` but it will spin for days if I let it.

What can I do to prevent getting stuck in `Copying to tmp table`? I have looked around and nowhere online can I find a very clear answer to what causes this except for some of the info [here](http://www.dbtuna.com/article.php?id=55) which I have tried to follow but to no avail.

I would think that there might be a better way for me to build the table rather than address memory concerns since the final table is small in rows (although each row is fairly large).  The general form of the build query to make the cache table is

```
Select col1,col2,col3... FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 on ... INNER JOIN tbl3 on ... 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT col4, col5, col6... FROM tbl4 INNER JOIN tbl5 on ...) 
  AS tbl6 on ... WHERE col2 > NOW() ORDER BY col3, col4
```

The left join is needed since I want to have copies of the data in the inner select if it exists, but don't want to limit by it if it doesn't.
I'm sorry if this isn't specific enough but if anyone has any idea how to prevent the `Copying to tmp table` I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: MySQL is perfectly capable of joining large tables with 100's of millions rows at extremely high speeds. Can you post your schema and explain plans for your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up indexes on tables? Indexes on columns which you are using in joins will speed up the select query. 
Maybe better solution for you in this case would be materialized view: http://fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

Comment: I have made sure that there are indices on everything which is getting join (except possibly the inner select statement since that is done dynamically) but I am reading about materialized views right now...

Comment: So it seems that mysql doesn't really have materialized view support and to implement them you are just computing things as you go and remembering them so that you don't have to calculate them at query time... for this query I can't remember it as I go and the building of the cache table is the materialized view refresh step... am I missing something?

Comment: ok now I see there is slightly more to materialized views when yu use mysql 'triggers' but unfortunately this won't work for my application because the join is the fundamental calculation that needs to be done to keep this up-to-date and that join is what I imagine is taking all the time

Comment: You can analyze a bit your query. Use EXPLAIN (your QUERY) to see what part of your query takes most time. After that you will be able to to improve that part of query or rewrite it in a different way. Try dissecting your query.. maybe just add one join at the time and see after which join takes up most time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the major principle of MYSQL optimisation has two poles (except for foreign key possibilities):

- optimization of size;
- optimization of speed.

Not taken for literally, the foolowing rule describes mysql optimization:

> the bigger the data size, the better is performance, and vice versa.

In a similar case we created an aggregated table as a real table, not cached, not a temporary table. This reduces amount of calculations and saves MYSQL does on the fly for your query. The query is then simplified, cleared of JOINs, GROUP BYs enclosed SELECTs, various functions etc. The data is maximally reduced and minimally updated beforehand (a single separate query or Cron task).

Creating indexes also downsizes and upspeeds. You usually include column names from your typical query in an index.